# I want to validate textarea,so that user canot enter words like phone number, email address or any url

Tags: javascript

I want to validate textarea,so that user cannot enter words like phone number, email address or any url .

If the user entered those values means how to identify those values by JavaScript 
(or)

How can I stop the user from entering these words using JavaScript?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script>
     function validate()
    {  
    var message=document.myForm.Name.value;
          var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
          if((message.value.match(phoneno))  
                {  
              alert("it has phone number");
              return false;  
                }  
              else  
                {    
                return true;  
                }  
        }
        var emailPat = /^(\".*\"|[A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/
    var EmailmatchArray = message.match(emailPat);
    if (EmailmatchArray != null) {
        alert("Text contains an email!");
        return false;
    }else{
       return true;
       }
          var Url = "^[A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_%&\?\/.=]+$";
       var isURL = message.match(Url);
       if (isURL != null) {
       alert("Contains a URL.");
       return false;
    }else{
       return true;
       }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form name="myForm"  
              onsubmit="return(validate());">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="send" id="send">

    </textarea>
<input type="button" value="submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this code not working

---

### it's new code --here am not getting any error here but here no alert working

new code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function validate()
{ 
alert("ok"); 
var message=document.myForm.send.value;
    var emailPat = /^(\".*\"|[A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/
      var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
      var Url = "^[A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_%&\?\/.=]+$";
       var EmailmatchArray = message.match(emailPat);
          var isURL = message.match(Url);
      if((message.value.match(phoneno)) && (EmailmatchArray != null)&&  (isURL != null))
            {  
          alert("it has phone number");
          document.myForm.message.focus();
          return false;  
            }  
         else{
             return (true);

         }


}

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return(validate());">

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="send" id="send">

</textarea>
<input type="button" value="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What went wrong with your code?

Comment: I hope you have some server sided validation, too.

Comment: You have to be precise on what's not working. If you have problems with your JavaScript code you should always check JavaScript console in your browser to see if there are any errors. If there are no errors in the console describe cases that you tested that give you wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are returning too early.  In the first block you check if there's a phone number, and if there is not - you return that the form is valid - before you go on to check for email and URL.

Answer (score 0):

In both new and old code the main error is in your HTML - you need `input` with `type="submit"`, not `type="button"` to submit the form. Without that function pointed in `onsubmit` attribute of `form` is not called.  And check syntax for pointing the function to be called in [`onsubmit` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp).

Fix this one and then debug the rest of code. You have to check all your brackets - both `{ }` and `( )`, as I see that you have some not-matching brackets in your old code. And you should not have `return true;` if the condition is not met, because the function will end in that place and another validations will never be checked.

If you'll still have problems post you can post your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and update your question with link. It will make it easier for us to debug it online.